# wget - HTML redirect issue

Tags: linux, wget

I can't get wget to work on the following link. (HTML redirect it seems)

http://www.limesurvey.org/en/stable-release/finish/25-latest-stable-release/407-limesurvey192plus-build120418targz

Found here_
http://www.limesurvey.org/en/stable-release

I searched and tried different options, no success. Help would be appricated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the HTML you get from that link:

```
<script>document.location.href='http://download.limesurvey.org/Latest_stable_release/limesurvey192plus-build120418.tar.gz';</script>
```

wget can't execute JS, so you have to copy the link and wget that:

```
wget http://download.limesurvey.org/Latest_stable_release/limesurvey192plus-build120418.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks. Looking at HTML I get(firefox11) its the one I pasted in my question. 
Looking at the source I get
<a target="_blank" href="/en/stable-release/finish/25-latest-stable-release/407-limesurvey192plus-build120418targz" title="Download" class="jd_download_url">limesurvey192plus-build120418.tar.gz

How to you get to view the true destination?

Comment: That link leads to an HTML document containing some JavaScript. In a web browser that JS is executed, taking you to a new location to download the actual file. wget isn't executing the JS, so it's not working. The actual download link is inside the JS code, as you can see above.