# Wget not downloading txt file in pycharm

Tags: python, download, pycharm, wget

I am coding in pycharm and i want to download the ticker symbols that is available here [EOD Data](http://eoddata.com/). However, you gotta create a free account there before you can proceed to download the files.

Here is my problem. I have the free account, and through the web browser (i'm using chrome), I am able to save the ticker txt file on my desktop.

But when I try to download it through `wget.download(url)`, it just saves the file as a html page. i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong..

Another note is that, on that website, there is a `download` button, which has the link `http://eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=SGX` so I paste this link in the url code above.

So the file ends up saving as `symbollist.aspx?.html` instead of the txt file that it was supposed to give me.

Any advises? Or any other ways I can address this issue?

Comment: [wget - HTML redirect issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273436/wget-html-redirect-issue) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You need use your username and password request. Access to resource is authenticate.

Better use **urllib2**.

Example:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request("http://eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=SGX")

base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Change **username** by your free username account and **password** by you password.

Comment: Thanks, but what do i need to change for python 3.4.3? because it seems that urllib2 is no longer in use for python 3.4.3.

Comment: Also, i get this error thrown: TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str

Any ideas?

Comment: @jakewong What OS you use?

Comment: I am using WIndows 7 64 bit. Python version is 3.4.3 32 bit. Have been reading about import urllib and trying the different requests methods to recreate the code you gave me above but still no luck.. :(

Comment: I think it might be better for me to use `Requests - HTTP for humans`  instead of wget.